# SQL with Dbeaver tool

Tags: sql

I want to sum units by mbr and date of service level and also want to add a column where the column would show the total of each previous units, for example

```
Mbr*id      DOS       units     Total_sum*\_units    
AA        1/1/2023    10            10   
AA        1/2/2023    10             20    
AA       1/3/2023     50             70    
AA       1/4/2023     50            120    
BB        1/1/2023    15            15    
BB        1/2/2023    10             25    
BB       1/3/2023     30             55    
BB       1/4/2023     45            100
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I am trying to use SQL for the above issue and using the tool called Dbeaver for the above scenario.

I want to sum units by mbr and date of service level and also want to add a colum where the colum would show the total of each previous units, for example

Any help would be much appreciated. I am trying to use SQL for the above issue and using the tool called Dbeaver for the above scenario.

Comment: Please edit your question and add to the question tags the RDBMS it is that you connect DBeaver to (sql server, oracle, postgres, mysql, mariadb, snowflake, teradata, etc). While most every RDBMS supports `GROUP BY` aggregation as well as Window Functions, the syntax and options may be different, leading to different answers for each platform.

Answer (score 0):

Using SUM as a window function:

```
select
    mbr_id,
    dos,
    units,
    sum(units) over (
        partition by mbr_id
        order by dos
        rows unbounded preceding
    ) as units_to_date
```

Comment: Thanks for your support on this. It is working properly. Thanks for the code.